# How to get initial of last name in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

Input : "Chris Gayle"

Required output : "Chris G"

I am currently using :

```
String inputStr = "Chris Gayle";
String[] strArr = inputStr.split(" ");
String output =strArr[0] + " " + strArr[1].charAt(0);
```

However, I was hoping to find an implementation that takes up fewer lines of code by using the 'replaceAll' function in the String class by using pattern matching techniques.

Comment: Don't measure code quality depending on the lines of codes. Your code is working fine and clear to understand - this could be worth more than a super complex regex some other dev needs to debug for 20 minutes to understand it.

Comment: And did you try it yet?

Comment: Regardless of which solution you choose, [make sure your real data won't surprise you](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't actually use regex for this.

**Example**

```
String input = "Chris Gayle";
System.out.println(input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf(" ") + 2));
```

**Output**

```
Chris G
```

The advantage here is that you can have names with multiple items, i.e.... `"Chris Foo Gayle"` --> `"Chris Foo G"`.

**Note**

This implies each item is separated by space, or at least the last name is. It would return unexpected results with something like `"Chris J.Gayle"`.

Even worse, if your input does not contain **any** space (i.e. single name). 
If that is a possible case, you should check that `input.lastIndexOf(" ") != -1` prior to invoking `substring`.

Answer (score 3):

Through replaceAll function.

```
string.replaceAll("(?<=\\s.).*", "");
```

The above regex would match all the characters which are preceded by a space and a single character.

Answer (score 1):

One line answer:

```
System.out.println("Chris Gayle".replaceAll("([a-z]*)$", ""));
```

Note: last name must start with capital letter.